# resize the selection/range using VBA

Tags: vba, offset

Simple question that is eluding me.  I have an active row selected.  I need to resize this range to add the next 22 rows using VBA.   E.g. its currently highlighting row 100 only. I would now like to expand the selection to highlight row 100 through 122.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a little more context. Do you want to expand the selection so that a larger range is selected or do you want to assign the result to a range variable? If the former -- why? There is almost always a better way to interact with the spreadsheet than use `Select` and `Selection`. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248).

Comment: I would like to expand the selection.  E.g. its currently highlighting row 100 only.  I would now like to expand the selection to highlight row 100 through 122.

Comment: So you're saying you want to _resize_ the selection?  Could you edit your question with a bit more detail please.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the selection use:

```
Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(22)).Select
```

This will work, although it isn't a bad idea to find a way to [avoid such selection-based code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248).

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.Resize(22).Select
```

Seems like the more straightforward method.